# JQuery doesn't work with parsed content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parsing

this problem is driving me crazy... I'm calling a PHP file through Ajax and parse it into my HTML content. I have to do it that way to have dynamic content, without refreshing the page.

My problem is that the parsed code won't execute any jquery stuff. I need a Jquery slider for example in the PHP file. But it's parsed as normal HTML and JQuery doesn't seems to recognise it.

Here's a sample:

The HTML File:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.7.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jscroller-0.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                // Add Scroller Object
                $jScroller.add("#scroller_container","#scroller","right",1);
                // Start Autoscroller
                $jScroller.start();
            });
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showGet(str)
            {
                if (str=="")
                {
                document.getElementById("center").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","content.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <input type="button" onclick="showGet(1)" value="showGet">
        </div>

        <div id="scroller_container">
         <div id="scroller">
          ...[Content]...
         </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the content.PHP file:

```
<?php

    echo "
        <div id=\"scroller_container\">
            <div id=\"scroller\">
                ...[Content]...
            </div>
        </div>
        "

?>
```

Executed, the HTML has a Button. If you click the button, it parses content.php into the `<div id="content></div>`.
The PHP contains the same `<div id="scroller" ....` as the HTML.

The HTML div works, the one in the PHP file not. WHY???? and how do I get it to work?

Many thx in advance for all hints!!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's Ajax functions? They are much easier to implement, plus they have executing scripts from Ajax results built in.

Comment: I would like to but I think I'm missing the required knowledge. Do you have an easy example for me?

Comment: The manual has some examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ah, but in this case, that's not the issue. The thing is that you need to run a separate `$jScroller.add()` for the new element.

Comment: unfortunally not, I can add as many as I wan't or even remove the scroller in the HTML file. The parsed content doesn't work. I'm reading the JQuery Examples right now. And are going to read the delegate API documentation but I think this is too high for my knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading content using jQuery ajax can be as simple as the following using load() method:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
/* loads a file into id=content and replaces exisitng html*/
$('#content').load( 'path/to/server/file', function(){
    /* new content exists, intialize event handling 
    and plugins for new html here*/


})
```

Comment: Wonderfull! That did the job. Shoud've ask you guys first. So much time wasted.... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To get dynamically added information access to jQuery functions you have to use delegate() or on() -

http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/